# The screen is not currently set to the recommended resolution

Tags: resolution, 1080p, 1080i

Just this morning after starting up, I see this message on the display monitor:

> The screen is not currently set to the recommended resolution
> Configure the PC resolution to 1080p/60hz
> Current Resolution:     1080i/60Hz
> Recommended Resolution: 1080p/60Hz

This message appears on a machine with Ubuntu 22.04.4.LTS
The monitor is LG Electronics 32 LG FH (1920x1080)

The system configuration has not changed in a couple years, though yesterday it did some updates (which is pretty much a daily thing) . I didn't pay attention to what they were so that may or may not be related.

In Display Configuration - System Settings the Resolution is 1920x1080(16:9). I see nothing to distinguish between "i" and "p"

The display does jitter a little.

What can I do?

Edit: Add setup screenshot
Edit 2:  xandr --verbose

1920x1080 (0x47) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz

1920x1080 (0x48) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
1920x1080 (0x62) 148.500MHz +HSync -VSync +preferred
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
1920x1080 (0x47) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
1920x1080 (0x63) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width  1920 start 1936 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
1920x1080 (0x48) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
1920x1080i (0x64) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace *current
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
1920x1080i (0x65) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
1920x1080i (0x66) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz

[image: setup]
[image: message]

Comment: "This message appears on a machine with Ubuntu …" – Are you sure it's not a message from the *monitor itself*? You interact with it by pressing buttons of the monitor, right? I'm pointing this out because the question is worded as if the message came from the "machine with Ubuntu". Yes, the video input is from the machine and the problem is probably with video config in Ubuntu, but if I'm right then "This message appears on a monitor connected to a machine with Ubuntu …" would probably be a better description.

Comment: You are correct, the message is from the monitor.

Comment: 1080i vs 1080p means: i = interlaced, p = progressive. The 1080i will display on 60hz but alternating lines, so technically its 30hz. See if you have a config setting somewhere in Ubuntu. If not, try changing to a different resolution and then back to 1080 to see if that works. If you can't get it to work, please post a screenshot of the resolution settings screen in your Ubuntu. Also, may fix itself if you restart the computer.

Comment: I tried restarting and also changing to a different resolution and back and these had no effect. Added setup to original question.

Comment: See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325830/displaying-at-1080i-instead-of-1080p) for a possible method of forcing 1080p.

Comment: I put the output of the xandr command in the question. It looks I want to set it to 0x47 but I don't know what to use for the --output parameter